# Error while importing facebook module in Python

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have installed facebook-sdk using below mentioned command:

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

But while importing it, I am facing an issue:

```
import facebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\facebook.py", line 222
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to `pip3 install --upgrade pip` Then do `pip3 install facebook-sdk` make sure to update first & make sure to use `pip3` if you have *both* `versions 2 & 3` as I do on my `Mac OSX`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an old syntax for catching exceptions.  It should have been replaced with the keyword `as` since Python 2.6, and it is probably not supported at all on Python 3.

Try to find another library that does support Python 3, or consider downgrading to Python 2.6 (which should really be a last-resort option).

You can review all details on [PEP 3110](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/).

Answer (score 7):

Check out This version: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/tree/b9b0de30402bb99387f35630446b5446a288d14b

Download it and install with:

```
python setup.py install.
```

It works for me:

```
$ pip freeze --local

facebook-sdk==1.0.0a0
```

:)

Comment: this helped me a lot! Thanks!!

Comment: You could also use pip install with the zip archive address: `pip install https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/archive/b9b0de30402bb99387f35630446b5446a288d14b.zip`

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation Facebook-SDK will not work with Python3.4 yet if you are using this version:
https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Update: `The SDK currently supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.4-3.7. The requests package is required.`