# Spyder ''Import Facebook Error'' despite of install conda facebook sdk

Tags: python, r, facebook, api, graph

I try to connect to facebook api with Python. I am using anaconda and also I get the following error:

I use anaconda

```
import json
import facebook

def main():
    token = "--token-key--"
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
    profile = graph.get_object('me',fields='first_name')    
    print(json.dumps(profile, indent=4))
```

**Error:**

> File "C:/Users/rabia.nural/Desktop/untitled6.py", line 9, in 
>   import facebook File
>   "C:\Users\rabia.nural\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\facebook.py",
>   line 222 except urllib2.HTTPError, e: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback?

Comment: I did this steps

Comment: I dont use pip I use conda env.I have no problem pip side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while importing facebook module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990928/error-while-importing-facebook-module-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

To install [facebook-sdk](https://anaconda.org/hargup/facebook-sdk) package from conda.

Run this,

```
conda install -c hargup/label/pypi facebook-sdk
```